# Webview load images from file but not from web in android

Tags: android, image, webview, load

Hello I want to load a HTML data into a WiebView. My html data contains two images, one is in the asset folder and the other is located on the web. My code is something like this:

```
String html  = "<html><body><img src="image1.jpg"><img src="http://www.example.com/images/image2.jpg"></body></html>";

webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```

But the webview only loads the first image and does not load the web image. Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: `http://www.example.com/images/image2.jpg` is not a jpg but html.

Comment: @greenapps I use this dummy url just as an example.

Comment: Don't do that. You cannot use it as an exmple as it is an existing url that does not work in your code because of the reason i told you. Very confusing in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok (except for the unescaped quotes) but you probably forgot to request internet permissinon for the webview. Add this to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I already had this permission in my manifest file and other parts of my app can connect to the internet without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

first to add internet permission in manifest.
second to write:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```

not:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```

because http shows web and file shows internal memory